# Evaluation of a polynomial using functions

Tags: r

I need some help creating a function that evaluates a polynomial of the form:

- P(x) = c1 + c2*x + c3*x^2 + ... + cn-1*x^n-2 + cn*x^n-1

With the arguments of vector x and coefficient vector. I need to use a for loop to calculate to polynomial sum, but not to calculate the different values of x. The last thing I need to do is do an error check if the coefficient vector's length is less than 2. Here's what I have tried:

```html
directpoly<-function(x,coef) {
  total=coef[1]
  for(n in length(coef)) {
    total<-total+coef[-1]*x^n-1
  }
  ifelse(length(coef)>2,"Vector is less than length 2")
}
```

I know that attempt is probably embarrassingly terrible but I'm very new to this program and very out of my depths, I've never coded in anything before. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `total<-total+coef[-1]*x^n-1` - why are you using `coef[-1]` ? `ifelse(length(coef)>2,"Vector is less than length 2")` shouldn't it be <2 ? and you are not providing else argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x <- 3
coefs <- c(4,5,3,1)
n <- length coefs 
result <- sum(coefs * x^(0:(n-1))
```

For the check:

```
if(n < 2){
  stop("n must be > 1")
}
```